# Parallax footer not working in Safari/Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I was following this [creating an 'under the rug' parallax footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139846/creating-an-under-the-rug-parallax-footer) to create a parallax footer and when it is in Chrome all goes well, but in Safari and Firefox it doesn't. The thing is, I don't even have vertical scroll in those browsers and I don't know why.

I hope someone can help me. The URL is http://inopia.net/attis/ and the interesting code is this:

```
#wrapper {

border-bottom: 25px solid white;
margin-bottom:180px;
background: url('img/fondo-test.jpg') no-repeat top left;
position: absolute;
border-right: 20px solid white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
}
#footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:180px;
margin-top: 10px;
z-index: -2;
background-color:grey;
color: white;
margin-left: -2px;
 }
```

I searched everywhere and I can't find the reason why the footer doesn't appear in those browsers. Any idea about what the problem can be would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the position of the wrapper div from `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` fixes it in Firefox. I don't have Safari to test it in that I'm afraid.

Comment: Wow. So easy and I didnt get to it. Dont know why. Do you know why was this happening? Thanks @Courtney7 you saved me :)

Comment: Thanks! The `position: absolute;` setting was taking the wrapper div out of the 'flow' of the page and taking up 100% of the height of the parent element which was the body and therefore the whole view. I'm afraid I don't know why the behaviour differed so significantly between the browsers though!